# Reinstall Windows 8.1 : "the selected boot device failed"

Tags: windows, boot, restore, reinstall

I really need help, I searched for solutions for days with no results.

I had a problem with Windows (which was stuck on the "please wait" screen)
After several searches and unsuccessful attempts, I decided to reinstall windows even if I lose all my documents.

I have a multi boot with ubuntu, a debian and windows.

I created a bootable usb with windows 8.1. However during the boot, the PC does not recognize it, I got messages like "the selected boot device failed" or "insert boot disk and press any key".

What I have done :
Used 2 different USBs to be sure that the problem is not with the usb key.
Changed the order of uefi and legacy boot in bios to put usb first.
Enabled Legacy Support

I was also wondering if it was possible to reinstall windows via ubuntu, because I have access to this partition, so maybe I can delete this partition from ubuntu and reinstall?

PS : sorry for my english, its not my native language.

Comment: How do you create the Windows boot USB and from which ISO?

Answer (score 0):

A few questions.

How are you creating your bootable USB? Rufus? Or another app?

Is your USB drive USB 2.0 or 3.0? USB 2.0 can somethings work better for this.

I don't believe it's possible to install Windows from the Ubuntu partition. You could delete the Windows partition, but it will not make the USB boot.

Comment: With linux : ```sudo mkdosfs -n 'USB-Drive-Name' -I /dev/sdc -F 32``` and ```sudo dd if=filename.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4k``` (sdb was correct, i checked this with the  ```fdisk -l``` command and finally ```sync```
```sudo eject /dev/sdb```